# How to run a list of lists of commands in parallel using python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess

I am using subprocess to execute a perl script on multiple files. The script has an output argument and I want all the output from each parallel run to be written to that output.

what I have tried

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def proc_cmd(cmd_lst, outfile):
    proc_lst = []
    for cmd in cmd_list:
        with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
            run_proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=out, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
            proc_lst.append(run_proc)
    for proc in proc_lst:
        if proc.poll() is None:
            proc.wait()

outfile = 'results.txt'
cmd_lst = [['perl script.pl -i', 'f1.txt', '-s', 'h1.txt', '-o', 'results.txt'], ['perl script.pl -i', 'f2.txt', '-s', 'h2.txt', '-o', 'results.txt'], ['perl script.pl -i', 'f3.txt', '-s', 'h3.txt', '-o', 'results.txt']]
proc_cmd(cmd_lst, outfile)
```

Nothing gets written to my outfile when I run it. In fact, it doesn't seem like its working at all and no errors are printed. I am supposed to collect all results in my outfile. I need some help

Comment: do perl scripts write to `results.txt` when you run them directly using perl?

Comment: Yes it normally writes to result.txt